# How to add information to about screen of my cocoa app in Mac Os X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder, nib

I am pretty new in developing cocoa applications. I have developed a small UI application using cocoa. I wanted to add some information on about screen, currently it shows the app name and version which is 1.00.
Can any one help me how i can add some information in about screen, is it possible to add information programmatically instead of hard coding it ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a file `Credits.rtf` or `Credits.html` in the application bundle, containing the extra information. If that file exists, AppKit displays it in the standard about panel.

Comment: +1 This technical note has detailed information http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2006/tn2179.html